# How do I use jQuery toggle class to add class or remove element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm not sure why my code is not responding, everything looks correct to me. I'm new to using jQuery and trying to use `toggleClass` to have card info displayed when the card on my page is clicked. Initially, I'd like it to be hidden but able to be toggled on and off.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.card').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('inner-card.active');
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  width: 350px;
  height: 180px;
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.inner-card .active {
  display: none;
}

.inner-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  background: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="inner-card">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sunt, libero?</p>
    <a href="">Link goes here</a>
    <div class="img-div">
      <img src="../static/img/search.png" class="card-img" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It should go from this

[image]

To this

[image]

Comment: Can you try to change your code to this way?
$(this).toggleClass('inner-card active');
example link: https://jsbin.com/raluqofimi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are several problems. First of all, I believe you want to write the `display:none` CSS logic this way:

```
.inner-card.active{
    display: none;
}
```

This means that the inner card will be hidden if it also has the `active` class.

Secondly, I believe you need to rewrite the script this way:

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
     $('.card').click( function() {
         $(this).find(".inner-card").toggleClass('active');
     });
 });
```

When you use the `toggleClass` you need to use just the name of the class, not the selector (-> no dot). Also, from the CSS, it looks like you need to find the inner card element first.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/no2bqhdL)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.card').click(function() {
    $(this).find(".inner-card").toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  width: 350px;
  height: 180px;
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.inner-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  background: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="inner-card hidden">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sunt, libero?</p>
    <a href="">Link goes here</a>
    <div class="img-div">
      <img src="../static/img/search.png" class="card-img" alt="magnify lens">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```